# Display Double Quotes In Text Fields In Form Edit Pages

Tags: php, jquery, double-quotes

I have number of forms and each form has number of input text fields. The problem that am facing now is,I couldn't show strings with double quotes in text fields.I know we can fix this problem using htmlspecialchars().But I have to do it for each text fields in each form,this will not be a simple task for now.So am seeking a solution,which we can solve it using jquery for all text fields in the project.Please help me to come out from this issue.

All the form data are coming from database.

What am expecting :

```
Input :test"123"data;
Output in text box :test"123"data;
```

Comment: Does the data come out of a DB? How do you create the output? Show some code, what you've tried, .. .

Comment: Can you send some example of code?
I'm not sure I get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the quotes, like this:

```
$('#test').val("\" \"");
```

More for your example ...

```
$('input').each(function(){
    $(this).val("\" \"");
});
```

Comment: I will try now and let you know.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure, and let me know if I misunderstood your question. That could definitely be the case

Comment: Hi,it is replacing actual value to " ".For example if am input value as test"123 after form submit it is displaying as "".

Comment: @SujathanR So could you give me an example of what you want, that would be helpful, thanks

Comment: @SujathanR Where is this data coming from? Because this works...

`var string = "123\"test \"data";
$('#test').val(string);`

Comment: All the data are coming from database after saving the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63342/discussion-between-what-have-you-tried-and-sujathan-r).